# Write a C program that accepts some integers from the user and find the highest value and the input position

Tags: c

i inputed 5 numbers 8,10,25,75,100.If we refer to if(number[j]>max)=>(number[0]>max)=>(8>0),result might be 8.But exact answer is 100,why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5
int main() 
{
int number[MAX], i, j, max=0, num_pos=0;
printf("Input 5 integers: \n");
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    scanf(" %d", &number[i]);
}

for(j = 0; j < MAX; j++) 
{
    if(number[j] > max) {
        max = number[j];
        num_pos = j;
    }
}
printf("Highest value: %d\nPosition: %d\n", max, num_pos+1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ps.  Although C is case-sensitive, it is probably bad form to have a constant `MAX` and a variable `max` as well.   The compiler knows they are different, but humans may have momentary confusion when reading this.

Comment: What happens if the user enters five negative numbers?

Comment: If all inputs were negative numbers, this code would incorrectly report 0 as the max.  Recommend `int max = INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 2):

> If we refer to if(number[j]>max)=>(number[0]>max)=>(8>0),result might be 8.

Yes, `8 > 0`, which is the first iteration.

In the next one, you will have `10 > 8`, which will also be true.

Until you reach `100 > 75`, and `100` will be the highest.